# State if each of the objects' set is well-defined or not.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, well-orders

Q. 1.1 taken from book titled: First-Semester Abstract Algebra:
A Structural Approach, by:  Jessica K. Sklar.

State if each of the below objects stated below is a well-defined set or not.

1. $\{z\in \mathbb{C}, |z|=1\}$.
2. $\{x \; ε \;R+, \;\text{is sufficiently small}\;\}$.
3. $\{q \;ε \;Q : q \;\text{can be written with denominator}\; 4.\}$
4. $\{n ε Z, n^2 < 0.\}$

Have attempted, and request vetting of the same below.

> 1. Yes, it is well defined as though infinite number of such complex numbers might exist, but each satisfies the fact that if $z= x+iy$, then $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1$.

> 2. Not well defined, unless state the numbers in a given range from some real number.
>    Say, set of numbers in range $0.01$ from $2.345$. Then, all real numbers in range from $2.335$ to $2.355$.

> 3. All rationals are defined in form ($\frac pq$, with $p,q$ as integers) with no common factor between $p,q$. So, the set is of all rationals s.t. $q=4$, hence $p$ is not expressible as a multiple of $4$.Hence, this set is well-defined.

> 4. Such set is empty, as square of any integer (positive, zero or negative) is always either $0$ or positive. Hence, this set is well-defined.

Comment: Hope that no response of any sort means am correct totally.

Comment: You are correct that all but 2. are well-defined, but your explanations are a little off. (2) is not well defined because there is no clear definition of "sufficiently small", so one has no way of determining whether any particular number is in or out. For the other three, there is a clear means of determining if any particular number is in the set, and that is all that is needed. For (1) and (4) you bring up irrelevant details, but there is nothing wrong in your discussion or conclusion. But what you say in (3) is not correct.

Comment: Rationals are defined as ratios of integers, with the only requirement being that the denominator is not $0$. Every rational *can* represented by a ratio with no common factors between numerator and denominator, but it is not required. And there is nothing in the set definition that indicates the numerator should not be divisible by $4$. All the integers are in this set, because $n = \frac{4n}4$. All multiples of $\frac 12$ are also in this set because $\frac n2 = \frac{2n}4$. It is not just numbers $\frac p4$ for odd $p$.